# Looking for an efficient way to convert a dataframe (or matrix) to a triplet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.now()
print('Starting time,'+str(start))
dict1 = {'id':['person1','person2','person3'], \
         'person1':['A','','', ], \
         'person2':['B','E',''], \
         'person3':['C','F','G',], }
demo = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
demo
demo.set_index(["id"], inplace=True)
demo


Out:
         
        person1 person2 person3 
person1    A       B       C
person2            E       F
person3                    G
```

My target format is as follows,

```
    target_1    target_2    target
0   person1     person1       A
1   person1     person2       B
2   person1     person3       C
3   person2     person1       E
4   person2     person2       F
5   person3     person3       G
```

Now **I want to convert it into a triple**, and I can think of using a loop to iterate over each element, but I think this may not be efficient, especially for large data sets, since I am new to python, so I want to find a more efficient way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use loop. Let's do `stack` to reshape the dataframe

```
demo[demo != ''].stack().rename_axis(['target_1', 'target_2']).reset_index(name='target')
```

Result

```
  target_1 target_2 target
0  person1  person1      A
1  person1  person2      B
2  person1  person3      C
3  person2  person2      E
4  person2  person3      F
5  person3  person3      G
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in demo.index.tolist():
    for j in demo.columns.values.tolist():
        print(demo.loc[i][j])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?